# Is possible Sanitize on Angular2 a HTML string allowing certaing tags?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, sanitization, html-sanitizing

I am sanitizing the current html (string value), I want to know if is possible only allow certains attributes. In this example the string only should keep the "id" attribute. Like this:

```
<h1 id="header">DomSanitizer</h1><script>ourSafeCode()</script>');
```

This is an example of my component.

```
import {BrowserModule, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div [innerHtml]="html"></div>
    `,
    })
    export class App {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        this.html = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<h1 id="header" class="headerClass" style="background-color: red" >DomSanitizer</h1><script>ourSafeCode()</script>') ;
    }
}
```

But instead I am getting all the attributes from the string, I was thiking on a regular expersion o something like that. But I want to know if I can filter the attributes (I am noob).

Comment: DomSanitizer may conduct to [security risk](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html). If you're not sure about what you're doing maybe you should consider another solution. For example, in your template `<h1 [attr.id]="CustomId">DomSanitizer</h1><script>ourSafeCode()</script>');` this a prepared statement that will not accept any other attribute.

Comment: You can create your own sanitizer implementation that incorporates a customized https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b4d444a0a7ee2c2b31b691d03b93368d1edd1572/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/security/html_sanitizer.ts to sanitize a subset of the elements. Seems it's not public. This means you'd need to copy the html_sanitizer.ts code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom logic to the sanitizer by overriding it. It's super hacky but it looks like:

```
class Something {
   constructor(sanitize: DomSanitizer) {
          sanitize.sanitize = function(context: SecurityContext, value: SafeValue | string | null) {
                // sanitize the string first because we still want to be secure
                const res = (sanitize as any).__proto__.sanitize.call(sanitize as any, context, value) || '';
               // match any attributes you don't want (or do want) and remove them  
              ...

           }
   }

}
```