# Allow specific HTML-attributes in innerHTML (Angular5)

Tags: angular, html-sanitizing

When using innerHTML, is there some kind of whitelist to allow some specific attributes without DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml or rewriting the latter completely? In the example below, `someAttribute` shouldn't be sanitized because it's whitelisted (or similar) but for `someOther`, the usual sanitization should take place.

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" someAttribute="foo" someOther="bar"></a>
```

This question is similiar to [this (unanswered) one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685118/is-possible-sanitize-on-angular2-a-html-string-allowing-certaing-tags) but regarding attributes, not tags.

Comment: What `innerHTML`? Why don't you want to use `DomSanitizer.bypass...`?

Comment: The example above is meant to be inside the innerHTML which is just a simple div like this: `<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>`. Bypassing the domsanitizer is exactly the thing I would like to avoid. So it should still stanitize the html but allow specific attributes which I define somehow somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I came to the conclusion that the best way is to use [Dynamic Components](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). This solution comes with the caveat that aot compiling isn't possible anymore, but perhaps Ivy Renderer will add some sugar to change this.